# What is the exact story of Lord Shiva & five Indras?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, indra

What was the exact story behind Lord Shiva & five previous Indras as per Mahabharata ? What was happened to them? What happened to the current Indra? How Lord Shiva had punished them?

Comment: But @YDS it doesn't mentions the full story.

Comment: full story would be in 1-2 chapters and mentioning that here would be in 'too broad' category..the above post has link/number of chapter from where u can read it...